# Playing Tetris on non-linear surfaces

Tags: game-design, geometry, 3d-meshes, curves

I am considering designing a Tetris game where instead of a traditional flat game board, the game will transform the board into different kinds of surfaces. I think I lack the appropriate mathematical terms to describe the behavior I'm looking for, but here is one example of the design. The board starts as a flat plane, and starts bending outwards until it forms a cylinder (at which point the entire board is not visible in one view). My question is what strategy can I use to implement the interactive graphics on non-uniform surfaces? I've seen that meshes are used a lot, but how can I show this Tetris board on any random mesh?

Here is an example of the transformation I am trying to make. Note that it will not be limited to curvature on a single axis.
[image]

Comment: So, basically [this](https://youtu.be/VLSKnVJMvHg)?

Comment: We can't really tell you how to design your own game

Comment: @Bálint I don't think they meant this as a design-based question (even though the tag is there). It sounds like they are asking about how to display this graphically. I could be wrong though so if the OP could clarify that would be great!

Comment: @Bálint That is somewhat what I had in mind. I can use the sphere as a starting point; however, it seems that the pieces have a fixed position. I would like to adapt that technique to an object that morphs into others. Also, the Tetris board is a flat plane so the 3-dimensional effect is an illusion of sorts. I added an image that demonstrates what kind of transformation i'm looking for. And yes, it is more about what kind of math/feature in a game engine I could use to create this effect.

Comment: Worth noting that the game of Tetrisphere was not truly happening on a sphere;  the game was actually being played on a strict cartesian 3D grid which wrapped around on the horizontal and vertical axes (so topologically a torus).  The game just used distortion to make it *appear* to be a sphere as you panned over the grid;  the sphere had no poles, and the rectangular tiles had none of the distortion which would have been required to make them fit without gaps on the surface of an actual sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just render your interactive 2D tetris game into a texture, instead of directly to the screen.

Then you can put that texture on any 3D object you want.